# Differential of element in the stabiliser

Tags: lie-groups, smooth-manifolds

$G$ a compact Lie group, $W$ a smooth G-manifold, $x \in W$.

Then as $G$ is compact $G \cdot x$ is an embedded submanifold.

Now the text I'm reading claims that for $g \in G_x$,

$dg_x : \text{T}_x W \to \text{T}_{g\cdot{x}}W=\text{T}_x W$

sends the tangent space of the orbit to itself by the identity map. However, I'm having difficulty showing this is actually the identity map  on $\text{T}_{x}G\cdot{x}$. I've tried passing to $G/G_x$ but as $G$ is not necessarily Abelian I don't think this is any easier. Is there something obvious I'm missing?

Comment: I don't understand the statement (what does $T_xG$ mean?). Consider the group of rotations acting on Euclidean space. The group fixes the origin but does not act trivially on the tangent space. Is that a counterexample?

Comment: Here $G\cdot{x}$ is the orbit $\text{Orb}{x}$ as an embedded submanifold of W. I think your example is correct in the fact that it doesn't act trivially on the tangent space of the origin as an element of the *whole* Euclidean space. However the orbit of the origin is just itself and the action does act trivially on the tangent space of the orbit.
*also I've just seen the confusing notation: $\text{T}_{x}G\cdot{x}$ is meant to be $\text{T}_{x}(G\cdot{x})$

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Comment: What about taking $SO(3)$ acting on the unit sphere? The stabilizer of a point is a copy of $SO(2)$ which acts nontrivially on the tangent space (the action is transitive so the orbit is all of $S^2$)? I don't think the statement is true unless $G_x$ is normal, which would imply every point in the orbit of $x$ has the same stabilizer.